# Deployment of third party jar in wildfly-9.0.2.Final

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-9

In order to visible external jars to more than one application i usually placed external jars at $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib directoy in JBOSS 5.x.These jars were automaically up at startp of AS.
How this will i do in wildfly-9.0.2.Final.

@Sam Thankx for reply
But still i am getting error , Kindly please see my scenario as following
Structure

1. There is jar archive named as test.jar is present in test.ear
2. In test.jar there is EJB3 session bean java class. In this class there is import stmt as.

   import com.oracle.asmc.ejb3.statelesssession.SLE3DecryptLocal;
3. Above package 'com.oracle.asmc.ejb3.statelesssession.SLE3DecryptLocal' is present in testclient.jar

Note - Above testclient.jar is not part of test.ear.(I want to access this testclient.jar from multiple EARs)

To deploy test.ear,i have done following steps

1. ./jboss-cli.sh -c (present in bin directory)
2. module add --name=testclient --resources=~/client_jar/testclient.jar
3. I have added following configuration in jboss-deployment-structure.xml and placed in META-INF directory while creating test.ear.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>       
      <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
     <deployment>
     <dependencies>
          <module name="testclient" />
     </dependencies>
   </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
4. For deploying Test.ear applicaiton, accessed 'http://127.0.0.1:9990/' and travesed link Deployments --> Add -->Add Deployment --->FINISH
   But still got following error.

   ```
   12:19:22,439 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "test.ear" (runtime-name: "test.ear")
   12:19:22,602 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "test.jar")
   12:19:22,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "test.war")
   12:19:23,524 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test.ear
   12:19:23,631 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
   12:19:23,842 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."test.ear"."test.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."test.ear"."test.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "test.jar" of deployment "test.ear"
     at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.oracle.test.SlsTestBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.test.ear.test.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
   ... 5 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/oracle/asmc/ejb3/statelesssession/SLE3DecryptLocal
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
     ... 10 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/oracle/asmc/ejb3/statelesssession/SLE3DecryptLocal from [Module "deployment.test.ear.test.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    ... 15 more
   ```

@Sam thankx for reply

I added 'jboss-deployment-structure.xml' in META-INF of test.jar.

Note- Yes, I am accessing 'com/oracle/asmc/ejb3/statelesssession/SLE3DecryptLocal' (present in testclient.jar module) from test.jar.

Now my test.ear contains

1. META-INF/application.xml
2. test.war
3. test.jar('jboss-deployment-structure.xml' present in META-INF directory of this test.jar )

But still i am getting following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.oracle.asmc.ejb3.statelesssession.SLE3DecryptLocal
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
... 10 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oracle.asmc.ejb3.statelesssession.SLE3DecryptLocal from [Module "deployment.test.ear.test.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
... 15 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class loading has completely changed with WildFly. You can read more information [at]

> Since WildFly 8, Class loading is considerably different to previous versions of JBoss AS. Class loading is based on the JBoss Modules project. Instead of the more familiar hierarchical class loading environment, WildFly's class loading is based on modules that have to define explicit dependencies on other modules. Deployments in WildFly are also modules, and do not have access to classes that are defined in jars in the application server unless an explicit dependency on those classes is defined.

More information can be found on the [WildFly 9 Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

Basically, you can add a module with your shared libraries and make your deployment depends on it.

For exemple, you could use the jboss-cli (located in the bin folder) to add a module with MySQL Connector Java

```
module add --name=org.mysql --resources=mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

Then to make your application see it, you can add a file called `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` containing the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.mysql" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The module name must match the name you specified in the module add command.

The file `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` can be omited if you add the module name in your `MANIFEST.MF` in the `Dependencies` section

Comment: where will i place configuration file --> 'jboss-deployment-structure.xml'

Comment: According to the logs you posted, test.jar is looking for the class `SLE3DecryptLocal` which I assume to be in your `testclient` module. Therefore, you should add a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in META-INF of test.jar

Comment: Thankx for reply! I had incorporated the changes as suggested by  you, But still test.ear is not deployed. Kindly see edited section.

Comment: I was wrong, the documentation says that the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` must be placed in the top level deployment which is in this case the ear. I just made a quick project that you can checkout at https://github.com/samcontesse/q34940005. I used a @Schedule to trigger a Singleton that depends on a module class.

Comment: I made a mistake, i didnt write 'export=true' in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. So after corrrecting this error and placing configuration file at the top level of deployment(.ear-->META-INF-->jboss-deployment-structure.xml), Now it is working fine.