# failing in deployment with hibernate to wildfly 10

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Deploying a hibernate-enabled webapp to wildfly 10.
My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.User</class>
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/reportbuilderback-ds.xml, you
         can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/reportbuilderback-ds.xml -->
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/reportbuilderwebservices"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="test"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="test"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have the JDBC oracle driver in /modules/org/postgres/main.
The module.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgres">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1211.jre6.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Part of my standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/PostGreDS" pool-name="PostgrePool">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reportbuilderwebservices</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgres</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>reportbuilderwebservices</user-name>
                        <password>reportbuilderwebservices</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="postgres" module="org.postgres">
                        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

However, when I'm deploying, I get the following server output:

```
13:45:20,705 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
13:45:21,187 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
13:45:21,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
13:45:23,522 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment reportbuilderback.war
13:45:23,534 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found reportbuilderback.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called reportbuilderback.war.dodeploy
13:45:23,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:45:23,638 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
13:45:23,661 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
13:45:23,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:45:23,797 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
13:45:23,811 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
13:45:23,849 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:45:23,855 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
13:45:23,903 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
13:45:23,938 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
13:45:23,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
13:45:23,961 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
13:45:24,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
13:45:24,280 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
13:45:24,311 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
13:45:24,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgres
13:45:24,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
13:45:24,390 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:45:24,709 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
13:45:24,888 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
13:45:24,897 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
13:45:25,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
13:45:25,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
13:45:25,209 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
13:45:25,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/PostGreDS]
13:45:26,023 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
13:45:26,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "reportbuilderback.war" (runtime-name: "reportbuilderback.war")
13:45:26,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
13:45:26,448 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
13:45:26,516 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
13:45:26,601 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:45:26,599 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:45:26,605 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:45:26,605 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:45:26,599 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:45:26,607 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
13:45:26,777 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
13:45:27,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
13:45:28,008 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'reportbuilderback.war#primary'
13:45:28,057 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]
13:45:28,116 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment reportbuilderback.war
13:45:28,305 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
13:45:28,305 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.10.Final}
13:45:28,308 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
13:45:28,311 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
13:45:28,370 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
13:45:28,747 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
13:45:29,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'reportbuilderback.war#primary'
13:45:29,221 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
13:45:29,224 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."reportbuilderback.war#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."reportbuilderback.war#primary": org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 30 more

13:45:29,232 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "reportbuilderback.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"reportbuilderback.war#primary\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"reportbuilderback.war#primary\": org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"reportbuilderback.war#primary\""],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
13:45:29,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "reportbuilderback.war" (runtime-name : "reportbuilderback.war")
13:45:29,278 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."reportbuilderback.war#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."reportbuilderback.war#primary": org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

13:45:29,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
13:45:29,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:45:29,604 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 9539ms - Started 403 of 670 services (18 services failed or missing dependencies, 404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
13:45:29,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'reportbuilderback.war#primary'
13:45:29,761 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment reportbuilderback.war (runtime-name: reportbuilderback.war) in 71ms
13:45:29,868 WARN  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0357: Notification of type deployment-undeployed is not described for the resource at the address []
13:45:29,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "reportbuilderback.war" (runtime-name: "reportbuilderback.war")
13:45:29,874 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".WeldStartService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 2 more ] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."reportbuilderback.war#primary" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".WeldStartService, service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 3 more ] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."reportbuilderback.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.session (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service org.wildfly.request-controller.control-point."reportbuilderback.war".undertow (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./reportbuilderback.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."reportbuilderback.war#primary"

13:45:31,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (management I/O-2) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 2,5,management-handler-thread]
13:45:34,325 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found reportbuilderback.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called reportbuilderback.war.dodeploy
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: have you added jdbc-postgresql.jar to your classpath. From log we can understand that the jar file is missing. Can you post the standalone.xml to check if there is any problem in datasource configuration

Comment: Quite alarming to see people making claims and asking for information that is already provided and disproven in the posted content. You defined the module which is fine - is the jar you mention in the module XML physically present in the same folder?

Comment: Absolutely. The jar postgresql-9.4.1211.jre6.jar is present in the subfolder /modules/org/postgres/main of my wildfly root, together with the module.xml mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure if the subfolder main is also necessary in /org/postgres? Just removed main and moved my jar and module.xml up one level to /modules/org/postgres, however still same result.

Comment: Your configuration seems ok since the server logs 
**13:45:24,311 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
13:45:24,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgres** I have the impression you have a side-effect. Try to load the class without hibernate with Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"). If it works, the problem concerns Hibernate. Otherwise, I have no idea

Comment: David, thanks for the assistance, but I'm kinda new to this whole hibernate and wildfly ecosystem. I'm not quite sure what you're asking me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself says

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
```

which means the **postgre jar** file is not found by wildfly. Refer following to see how to configure third party jar files in wildfly.

[Deployment of third party jar in wildfly-9.0.2.Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940005/deployment-of-third-party-jar-in-wildfly-9-0-2-final)

Comment: Well how do you know, this actually worked. I added a MANIFEST.MF file in the META-INF folder, with content "Dependencies: org.postgres", now it deploys without any problems... Thanks!!

Comment: Well, It happened with me when I was setting up mysql database. I got the same type of error because I did not add mysql dependancy. Then I read that wildfly has a different mechanism for including third party jar files.